# How to implement the split button in Xcode 4.3?

Tags: cocoa, split-button

I want to implement the buttons in my Mac app like the split button on Xcode's menubar. How to do that?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class you're looking for is `NSSegmentedControl`. Read up about it in the [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSegmentedControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html).